# Number expected error in IE on comparing strings

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have a sort function in one of javascript plugins and the code looks someting like this:

```
groups = groups.sort(function (a, b) {
    a = a.content.toString().toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '');
    b = b.content.toString().toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '');
if(a > b){ //stops and gives error here
return 1;
}
if(a < b){
return -1;
}
return 0;
});
```

`a.content` is actually a string itself (but just for the sake of IE, I added `.toString()` as well in the code.
On all other browsers, the above code runs fine on all browsers but on IE 8, the above code shows shows a JavaScript error and stops at the line shown in the code above. The console shows a message "Number expected" at this line.

(Sometimes the `a.content` might have some html in this form as well ->
`"<span>Sample String</span>"`. 
Not sure if that can result in the error in IE8 but the issue occurs only in this browser)
How do I get rid of this error?

Comment: Since it's browser specific it requires some tinkering, as it's not obvious to me at least what's wrong in IE. Could you create a jsfiddle  with some sample values loaded into groups so we could replicate the error?

Answer (score 2):

```
a = a.content.toString().toLowerCase()
```

use this instead

```
var a1 =    a = a.content.toString().toLowerCase()
```

as theres an issue with ie < 9 with toLowerCase returning unknown data types randomly... if you dont re-assign the variable in sort, it will behave.

Comment: flag this as answered?

Answer (score 0):

I remember there was some issue in IE when IE added some blank space... Try to trim.

Or... did you try to compare strings using .localeCompare?

```
alert('a'.localeCompare('b'));
alert('a'.localeCompare('a'));
alert('b'.localeCompare('a'));
```

Comment: I tried `localeCompare` but that screws up my sorting. For eg: `Relaucch112` comes before `Relaunch` or something like that. I didn't try to see the localeCompare if that was working on IE since the sorting was not exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Also, the code I have written for `.replace()` in my post above will remove the spaces, so I think that shouldn't be a problem